# jquery ajax builtn variables

Tags: jquery

I am just wondering in jquery .ajax has builtin variables like $_POST in php. In the code below how is variables like data, request etc comes from

```
 $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "bin/process.php",
    data: data,
    success: function(request) {
      //display message back to user here
    }
  });
```

Comment: Please be more specific about. can't get you.

Answer (score 1):

`data` is your variable within the request scope. `request` is the output of `bin/process.php`.